# Listview highlighted selected item remain even closing an app

Tags: android

I'm having a trouble on how can I save and read the highlighted item in my listview , I use shared preferences below but I don't know the next step please help me how can do this, any help is much appreciated thanks

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozKOK.png)

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> list_items = new ArrayList<>();  //global variable
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;     //global variable
private boolean[] isSelected;  //global variable

text_listview = findViewById(R.id.textlistview);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list_items);
text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
isSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()];

text_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            isSelected[position]=true;
            text_listview.setItemChecked(position,true);
            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue));

            saved(position, view);
        }
    });
}
public boolean saved(final int position, final View view){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit1 = sp.edit();

    mEdit1.putInt("Status_size", position);

    for(int i=0;i<list_items.size();i++)
    {
        mEdit1.remove("Status_" + i);
        mEdit1.putString("Status_" + i,list_items.get(i).toString());
    }
    return mEdit1.commit();
}
```

Comment: @Mike M. can you help me with this module PLEASE , Im out of solution. So far this is the hardest  part for me