# Highlighted item in listview remain android

Tags: android

Is there any solution to save the highlighted selected item in listview ? even you close the app?
I've already ask here once but no one replies, any help is appreciated

> [Listview highlighted selected item remain even closing an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977831/listview-highlighted-selected-item-remain-even-closing-an-app)

Comment: Use _SharedPreference_

Comment: Please don't post a question just to point to a previous question. If you have new information, edit the original question to add it, and it will get bumped to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry I'm just newbie in stackoverflow, thanks for the advice